# How to save/load/delete an entity from a particular namespace using Objectify?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Can anyone point me to **Objectify sample code** to save/load/delete an entity that belongs to a particular **namespace** ?

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [set namespace via `NamespaceManager`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy#Setting_the_Current_Namespace) as you would with low-level API. See the [first answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/objectify-appengine/namespace/objectify-appengine/CjHQJJnrXso/T3aJPWHp5vAJ) from Objectify author.

Answer (score -1):

as per [Objectify Docs](http://objectify-appengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/googlecode/objectify/ObjectifyFactory.html#MEMCACHE_NAMESPACE), the way to specify the namespace is overiding the getRawMemcacheService() function of ObjectifyFactory, after that, with that Factory, you will operate under that namespace

**EDIT:** seems that this is a not correct answer from me, i'll investigate a little more, sorry